# Flexdashboard containing runtime:shiny saves html output in tmp folder and the html file shows a blank page

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, rstudio-server, googlevis

I have been searching for this problem for a few hours and I cannot seem to find the right solution. I would appreciate any help regarding how to fix this.

I have a flexdashboard in my RStudio Server, and in it, I have one `gvisGeoChart` that I have wrapped in a `dynamic UI`. Like below:

```
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  html_document: default
  orientation: rows
  vertical_layout: scroll
  theme: bootstrap

runtime: shiny

library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
library(googleVis)


# #create a ui interaction:
uiOutput("dynamic")

#render the ui:
output$dynamic <- renderUI({
   htmlOutput("myTable")
 })

#plot the chart
output$myTable <- renderGvis({gvisGeoChart(buyer_eur, locationvar = 
"Buyers", colorvar = "Sum of Invoices",
         options = list("regions",
                        height = "auto",
                        width = "auto")})
```

My dashboard renders beautifully when I run it inside my RStudio. It shows the interactive plot. However, I do not see any html output from this `.Rmd` file saved in the same directory (which knitting usually does). Instead I see the file is saved in a `/tmp` folder, like this:

```
Output created: /tmp/RtmpYG0i95/file320c5f4901a.html
```

I go and get this file, but when I open it on my local machine, I see a blank page only.

Can someone please tell me how I can produce an `html` file out of this dashboard that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but as far as I know, any document with `runtime: shiny` will require some form of shiny back-end to be evaluated in, hence no usable html will be generated that can be viewed outside of the context of a [Shiny server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/) or publication tools like [Rstudio connect](https://www.rstudio.com/products/connect/) or [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/). In Rstudio (server) you should also observe that the "knit" button is replaced by a "Run Document" button, which makes it possible to run the document locally by creating a shiny server to evaluate it in (see the documentation of `rmarkdown::run()`.